# Getting java.net.MalformedURLException while verifying the response code

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

I am getting the error below while verifying the response code of the URLs in the following snippet. I am fetching all the URL's present on the page and verifying if the response code is 200 or not.

```
XSSFCell cell3 = newRow.createCell(2);
cell3.setCellValue(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode()); 
System.out.println("URL : = " + url + "Response Code : = " + httpURLConnect.getResponseCode());
```

The error message is:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: XSSFCell cell3 = newRow.createCell(2);
          cell3.setCellValue(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode());
          System.out.println("URL : = " + url + "Response Code : = " + httpURLConnect.getResponseCode());

Comment: What is the value of url var ?

Comment: @NishantTripathi please make your above comment part of your question by editing it, it is important to include the code in your question instead of comment, as it might get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As per java api, MalformedURLException will be thrown to indicate that a malformed URL has occurred. Either no legal protocol could be found in a specification string or the string could not be parsed. 
Seems URL you are trying to connect is not a valid URL. A typical URL could have the form http://www.example.com/index.html, which indicates a protocol (http), a hostname (www.example.com), and a file name (index.html).

Debug your application and see what is your URL is missing to become a valid URL